# redux-form is Destroying my state once the component is unmounted, what gives?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-form

I am not passing in any special config settings nor am I setting/or calling Destroy... but my state is being cleaned...  anyway to prevent this? I need the state to stick around as I need that data thruout my application.

```
prev state: I see it in there... via redux-logger
action: redux-form/Destroy
next state: it's gone.
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I'm creating a login page.  It works fine until when I don't show the login form anymore and my state gets wiped out from the `redux-form/DESTROY`.

Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: It looks like in my case it was programmer error.  Maybe this helps someone else who made the same mistake.  My reducer was returning `initialState` for the default case instead of just `state`.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The form's state subtree *is* destroyed when the form is unmounted, by design. This is the default and expected behaviour.

**From [v6.2.1](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/pull/2113) onwards** there is a form config property `destroyOnUnmount`, which explicitly enables/disables the state-clearing behaviour on a specific form ([docs here](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/#-destroyonunmount-boolean-optional-))

```
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

reduxForm({
  form: 'example',
  destroyOnUnmount: false
})(...)
```

This is useful when you have a form whose state you wish to preserve if the user abandons it halfway though, navigates away, and then returns later.

Comment: this now seems to be working as of v6.2.1: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/releases/tag/v6.2.1

Comment: In my situation I also needed to add `keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true` in addition to `destroyOnUnmount: false`.

Comment: you're a life saviour

Comment: For me its not working still now. I am using redux form version 7.04

Comment: @Pete Thanks. I was looking for this. Somehow `destroyOnUnmount ` was not working, it was saving the redux state, but was reinitialising when opening the form. That helped me.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably merging `redux-forms`'s state into yours, you should have it under separate key. `Destroy` action returns undefined, which is okay, if the redux-forms reducer only manages it's part of the store.

Make sure you're following step #1 in this tutorial, specially the `form: formReducer` part :
https://redux-form.com/7.2.3/docs/gettingstarted.md/#step-1-of-4-form-reducer

Comment: yeah, I believe I have everything wired up.. just odd.. I'll recheck everything - thanks.

Comment: link not available :(